# XNA: What can cause SpriteBatch.End() to throw a NRE?

Tags: c#, xna

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong here:

```
public void Draw(GameTime gameTime) // in ScreenManager
{
    SpriteBatch.Begin(SpriteBlendMode.AlphaBlend);
    for (int i = 0; i < Screens.Count; i++)
    {
        if (Screens[i].State == Screen.ScreenState.HIDDEN)
            continue;

        Screens[i].Draw(gameTime);
    }
    SpriteBatch.End(); // null ref exception
}
```

SpriteBatch itself is not null.

Some more context:

```
public class MasterEngine : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{

    public MasterEngine()
    {
        graphicsDeviceManager = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Components.Add(new GamerServicesComponent(this));

        // ...

        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(graphicsDeviceManager.GraphicsDevice);

        screenManager = new ScreenManager(assets, gameEngine, graphicsDeviceManager.GraphicsDevice, spriteBatch);
    }

//...

   protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        screenManager.Draw(gameTime); // calls the problematic method
        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
}
```

Am I failing to initialize something properly?

**UPDATE:**

As an experiment, I tried this to the constructor of `MasterEngine`:

```
spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(graphicsDeviceManager.GraphicsDevice);

spriteBatch.Begin();
spriteBatch.DrawString(assets.GetAsset<SpriteFont>("calibri"), "ftw", new Vector2(), Color.White);
spriteBatch.End();
```

This does not cause a NRE. hmm....

**UPDATE 2:** This does cause an NRE:

```
protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
    spriteBatch.Begin();
    spriteBatch.End(); // boned here
    //screenManager.Draw(gameTime);
    base.Draw(gameTime);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be creating you `SpriteBatch` in Constructors of your Game class or your `DrawableGameComponent` classes as it's not guaranteed the `GraphicsDevice` has been initialized properly at that point. (and in fact you may end up initializing them with null graphics devices :P)

Move your `SpriteBatch` creation into the overridden `LoadContent` method

Same with your `ScreenManager`, your passing in a `GraphicsDevice` at the wrong point. If your `ScreenManager` inherits from `DrawableGameComponent` then you should have access to a `GraphicsDevice` property from inside it anyway, which you can use in the `LoadContent` method of you screen manage to load any content that the `ScreenManager` requires.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I've not used XNA for a long time, but shouldn't SpriteBatch be lowercase (or have another name), otherwise you'll be referencing the actual class SpriteBatch and not the instance?

Comment: nah, that doesn't cause a problem. (I changed it to lowercase anyway, and the problem persists.)